# .htaccess redirect part of url ?tmpl=component

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I have a URL like this

```
/projects/5-cockroft-renovation-after/detail/151-waterproofing-alberton.html**?tmpl=component**
```

I would love if I could redirect to

```
/projects/5-cockroft-renovation-after/detail/151-waterproofing-alberton.html
```

Basically hoping to remove the `?tmpl=component` of the URL entered in `.htaccess` this far I find my knowledge a tad limited on the subject.

Comment: I have tried htaccess redirect with different variants. I have also tried sef url redirect. This is a Joomla 2.5 website. Quite insane and yet I'm sure the fix is very simple indeed - yet it eludes so well :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these rules to the htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} tmpl=component
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}? [L,R]
```

Comment: Jon Thanx so much for the quick reply I'm afraid it's not quite kicking in like it should. if i may [link](http://www.fixitmaintenance.co.za/projects/5-cockroft-renovation-after/detail/151-waterproofing-alberton.html?tmpl=component) a copy of the actual htaccess can be seen here [link](http://www.fixitmaintenance.co.za/test.html) I've been at this for 3 hours this far Mistress google has left me in the cold I appreciate everyone's time as always.

Comment: @ElPaccino I forgot to add the `R` flag

Answer (score 2):

Basicly you add rules based on regular expressions to your .htaccess like this:

```
RewriteRule   ^(some regexp pattern)(another regexp pattern)$    /something/$1/$2  [R]
```

Values matched in bracers are than substituted with $1, $2, $3, and so on..

I suppose this should work for you:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+\.html).*$ $1 [R]
```

It should take text from the beginning to the .html and ignore all behind it.

Comment: Thankx so much I will continue on this as suggested.